# StyleGAN runtime phenomenom

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks

I was playing around with MobileStyleGAN pretrained model and multithreading and came along with an interesting phenomenom. After a while application is running MobileStyleGAN starts to produce video clip alike pieces.

And I am wondering does anyone have an idea what takes?

I made this lengthy video for it where you can see since it looks cool; https://youtu.be/8kpxHZK1NTQ

Here's the source code used in the video if it's any help; https://github.com/harism/i_style_gan

Comment: Here's one more video while trying to see how looping the GAN component output a few times into input react to all this; https://youtu.be/iVd7rve5Ja8

Comment: not really familiar with the model, but I heard of similar issues usign batch norm in GANs, as the EMA for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ creates dependence of the batch, and the batch history

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia could be I do not know GAN at all actually, I'm just amazed about it the model keeps producing human like images no matter what I do. I'm more used to see randomness produces different kinds of images. However, if you compare this state I got GAN into, could it be it's a bit same as LLM hallucinating, i.e I believe no one taught the model all this.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question and state it briefly that yes StyleGAN models do indeed come with sort of an gesture mapping. I have not tried those properly since I believe they are mainly computed with original StyleGANx models from The NVidia Helsinki office. Instead the smaller model made with smartphones as the target devices in mind MobileStyleGAN seems to have similarities too - and this is what I faced while writing my original question here.

To support my findings I leave this latest realtime capture of the current state I have achieved so far with MobileStyleGAN;  https://youtu.be/FqxbTijK41g